# Return values when recalling a function within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

Working on a program that visualises the growth of plants in a field. A function is called that enter code hereeturns a value as follows:

```
Field = InitialiseField()
```

Then the function:

```
def InitialiseField(): #function that gives the user a choice of creating a blank field or loading a text file
  def validate():
      Response = input('Do you want to load a file with seed positions? (Y/N): ')
      if Response.upper() == 'Y':
        Field = ReadFile() #creates a multidimensional array based on an external text file
        return Field
      elif Response.upper() == 'N':
        Field = CreateNewField() #generates new field with a single seed
        return Field
      else:
          print('Please enter either N/n or Y/y')
          validate()

  return validate() #return the updated field
```

When a user enters a valid response (N/n or Y/y) the program continues to run as would be expected. However when a user enters an invalid response and then after enters a valid response the InitialiseField() function returns a NoneType object instead of the second response?

When a user enters an invalid response the validate() function is recalled and I am assuming it is returning the NoneType object from the first loop upon completion before the second returns the correct value - how can I resolve this?

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Why do you wrap `validate` in `InitialiseField`? Are any of the variables set defined outside these functions?

Comment: masterfloda has the right answer v to the survival question, but really this isn't an appropriate use of recursion. Just loop until you get a value entry; this will also avoid the need for nested functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the answer in the title of your question :-) You need to `return` the value of `validate()`:

```
      print('Please enter either N/n or Y/y')
      return validate()
```

If you don't, your method does not return anything, which evaluates to `is None`

Also, you might want to read the [Python Styleguide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions): use lowercase characters for functions.

Comment: Ah yep that makes sense thank you!  With regards to styling - I am aware but this project is based from some A Level specimen files provided by an exam-board, they use the incorrect styling and we are required to use it!